# I am using shared preferences to save the tasks in my app. But it displays only the last added task?

Tags: android, task, sharedpreferences, android-notifications

[image: Displays the last entered details]
 I am creating a task manager to remind the task,
so i added the tasks, after added the task,
i have button called view to display the created tasks
but it displays only the last task.

Comment: you are then overwriting the share preference instead of appending to it I guess.

Comment: How can one figure out what you're doing wrong without seeing your code? And by the way, in your case database will be a better solution.

Comment: values in shared prefs are stored in key value pairs i.e you are using a key for saving your data in xml file and when you want use that you access that by its name. therefore you should use different name for saving different items

Comment: Display some code of your activity.

Comment: i think your problem is same key name and different value are use all time.so you get the last add value dear.Just change key every then seee.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing last added task is because shared preference stores values according to key value pair. So when you add some value with the same key in shared preference it gets over write. You can use different types of keys to store values in shared preference. But for better performance you can use database to do it and it will be the best solution in your case

Comment: Yes you can store alot data in shared prefrence but its good to use database if data is heavy and have to be related to each other

Answer (score 0):

because you are overwriting that share preference. save any task with different name will not overwrite the previous preference. and then access them by that name.

Comment: But i need to store more tasks for that how to use the shared preferences efficiently..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an SQLiteDatabase instead of SharedPreferences for such an App. There a lot of tutorials in the web too, that show step-by-step how to do it!